# WCF Service- The protocol 'https' is not supported

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl, wcf-security

I am developing a WCF service using WsHttpBinding and an SSL certificate for security.  Works perfectly in my local IIS, but when I publish I get the following error message;

> The protocol 'https' is not supported.

Here is my web.config file..

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="PeopleService.Service.PeopleService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://www.mywebsite.com/service/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" contract="PeopleService.Service.IPeopleService" name="BasicEndpoint"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I am using a ServiceHost factory to add my endpoints, so that I can load the SSL certificate from a physical file rather than from the certificate store.

```
public class PeopleServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public PeopleServiceHost(params Uri[] addresses) : base(typeof(PeopleService), addresses)
    {

    }

    protected override void InitializeRuntime()
    {
        Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
        Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpsHelpPageUrl = new Uri("https://www.mywebsite.com/service/PeopleService.svc/mex");

        ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        metadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
        metadataBehavior.HttpsGetUrl = new Uri("https://www.mywebsite.com/service/PeopleService.svc/mex");
        Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);

        var serviceCredentials = new ServiceCredentials();
        serviceCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\mywebsite.pfx", "password123", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        Description.Behaviors.Remove((typeof(ServiceCredentials)));
        Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceCredentials);

        base.InitializeRuntime();
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for days, but to no avail.  I've contacted by host and they have advised me that HTTPS is definitely supported and enabled in IIS.

Any help is really appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How is your published environment setup, any load balancing, routing through anything else?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the specific details, but I believe there is a load balancer in play yes.  I can find out if need be.

Comment: If the request is jumping to http, this could be your issue.  Long shot, but everything else you have seems alright at first glance.

Comment: I suspect that could be the case, I've read a few people saying similar things.  I'll ask the host if could be the case.

Comment: This was the response from the host.  "The load balancer sends the traffic to the backend web server over HTTP.  The HTTPS is handled by the load balancer."  I'm assuming that is the problem and the back end traffic must be over HTTPS?

Comment: I asked the host to secure the backend traffic with SSL, the response was "I can't add the SSL to each backend web server I'm afraid.  It might just be that you need to tell the app to do the SSL detection another way.  The header is HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO.".  I don't know of any way to do the SSL detection "another way"